# kubuntu 16.04 dont detect my hard drives

Tags: 16.04, sata

I install kubuntu 16.04 today and I have 4 hard drives but the installer only detect 2, I try all the choices in the BIOS, IDE, ACPI, same result.

Some thing interesting, the installer only see the disks that I put on the SATA connector number 5 and 6 on the notherboard.

Thanks for the help